# Passing Parameter values in URL

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I have one servlet for the add, delete, update and search functions.
I pass parameter in action on jquery. According to this parameter I put logic in my servlet.

The problem is that all other functions are working.
But when I put the same name in the action and servlet condition, I get url not found error.
If I use different names, not found error does not come. I have added my jquery and servlet code below:

```
/* 
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */    
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#doctorId").keypress(function (e)  
    {
        //if the letter is not digit then display error and don't type anything
        if( e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57))
        {
            //display error message
            $("#errmsg").html("Digits Only").show().fadeOut("slow"); 
            return false;
        }   
    });

    $('.btn-submit').click(function(e) {
        required = ["doctorId","speciality","employeeId","experience","qualification"];
        // Declare the function variables:
        // Parent form, form URL, email regex and the error HTML
        var $formId = $(this).parents('form');
        var formAction = $formId.attr('action');
        var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
        var nicReg=/^[0-9]{9}[vVxX]$/;
        var $error = $('<span class="error"></span>');

        // Prepare the form for validation - remove previous errors
        $('li',$formId).removeClass('error');

        $('span.error').remove();

        // Validate all inputs with the class "required"
        $('.required',$formId).each(function(){
            for (i=0;i<required.length;i++) {
                var inputVal = $('#'+required[i]).val();
                var $parentTag = $('#'+required[i]).parent();
                if(inputVal == ''){
                    $parentTag.addClass('error').append($error.clone().text('Required Field'));
                }
            }

            // Run the email validation using the regex for those input items also having class "email"
            if($(this).hasClass('nic') == true){
                var inputVal2=$('#nic').val();
                var $parentTag2=$('#nic').parent();
                if(!nicReg.test(inputVal2)){
                    $parentTag2.addClass('error').append($error.clone().text('Enter valid NIC'));
                }
            }

            // Check passwords match for inputs with class "password"
            if($(this).hasClass('password') == true){
                var password1 = $('#password-1').val();
                var password2 = $('#password-2').val();
                if(password1 != password2){
                    $parentTag.addClass('error').append($error.clone().text('Passwords must match'));
                }
            }                
        });

        // All validation complete - Check if any errors exist
        // If has errors


        if ($('span.error').length > 0) {

            $('span.error').each(function(){

                // Set the distance for the error animation
                var distance = 5;

                // Get the error dimensions
                var width = $(this).outerWidth();

                // Calculate starting position
                var start = width + distance;

                // Set the initial CSS
                $(this).show().css({
                    display: 'block',
                    opacity: 0,
                    right: -start+'px'
                })
                // Animate the error message
                .animate({
                    right: -width+'px',
                    opacity: 1
                }, 'slow');

            });
        } else {
            this.form.action = "DoctorServlet?method=add";
            $formId.submit();
        }
        // Prevent form submission
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    // Fade out error message when input field gains focus
    $('.required').focus(function(){
        var $parent = $(this).parent();
        $parent.removeClass('error');
        $('span.error',$parent).fadeOut();
    });

    $('.btn-delete').click(function(e){

        // Declare the function variables:
        // Parent form, form URL, email regex and the error HTML
        var $formId = $(this).parents('form');
        var formAction = $formId.attr('action');
        var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
        var $error = $('<span class="error"></span>');

        // Prepare the form for validation - remove previous errors
        $('li',$formId).removeClass('error');

        $('span.error').remove();

        // Validate all inputs with the class "required"
        $('.required',$formId).each(function(){
            var inputVal = $("#doctorId").val();
            var $parentTag = $("#doctorId").parent();
            if(inputVal == ''){
                $parentTag.addClass('error').append($error.clone().text('Required Field'));
            }

            // Run the email validation using the regex for those input items also having class "email"


            // Check passwords match for inputs with class "password"


        });

        // All validation complete - Check if any errors exist
        // If has errors

        if ($('span.error').length > 0) {

            $('span.error').each(function(){

                // Set the distance for the error animation
                var distance = 5;

                // Get the error dimensions
                var width = $(this).outerWidth();

                // Calculate starting position
                var start = width + distance;

                // Set the initial CSS
                $(this).show().css({
                    display: 'block',
                    opacity: 0,
                    right: -start+'px'
                })
                // Animate the error message
                .animate({
                    right: -width+'px',
                    opacity: 1
                }, 'slow');

            });
        } else {
            this.form.action = "DoctorServlet?method=delete";
            $formId.submit();
        }
        // Prevent form submission
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    // Fade out error message when input field gains focus
    $('.required').focus(function(){
        var $parent = $(this).parent();
        $parent.removeClass('error');
        $('span.error',$parent).fadeOut();
    });

    $('.btn-update').click(function(e){
        required = ["doctorId","experience","qualification"];
        // Declare the function variables:
        // Parent form, form URL, email regex and the error HTML
        var $formId = $(this).parents('form');
        var formAction = $formId.attr('action');
        var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
        var $error = $('<span class="error"></span>');

        // Prepare the form for validation - remove previous errors
        $('li',$formId).removeClass('error');

        $('span.error').remove();

        // Validate all inputs with the class "required"
        $('.required',$formId).each(function(){
            for (i=0;i<required.length;i++){
                var inputVal = $('#'+required[i]).val();
                var $parentTag = $('#'+required[i]).parent();
                if(inputVal == ''){
                    $parentTag.addClass('error').append($error.clone().text('Required Field'));
                }
            }

        // Run the email validation using the regex for those input items also having class "email"


        // Check passwords match for inputs with class "password"


        });

        // All validation complete - Check if any errors exist
        // If has errors



        if ($('span.error').length > 0) {

            $('span.error').each(function(){

                // Set the distance for the error animation
                var distance = 5;

                // Get the error dimensions
                var width = $(this).outerWidth();

                // Calculate starting position
                var start = width + distance;

                // Set the initial CSS
                $(this).show().css({
                    display: 'block',
                    opacity: 0,
                    right: -start+'px'
                })
                // Animate the error message
                .animate({
                    right: -width+'px',
                    opacity: 1
                }, 'slow');

            });
        } else {
            this.form.action = "DoctorServlet?method=update";
            $formId.submit();
        }
        // Prevent form submission
        e.preventDefault();


    });

    // Fade out error message when input field gains focus
    $('.required').focus(function(){
        var $parent = $(this).parent();
        $parent.removeClass('error');
        $('span.error',$parent).fadeOut();
    });
    $('.btn-search').click(function(e){

        // Declare the function variables:
        // Parent form, form URL, email regex and the error HTML
        var $formId = $(this).parents('form');
        var formAction = $formId.attr('action');
        var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
        var $error = $('<span class="error"></span>');

        // Prepare the form for validation - remove previous errors
        $('li',$formId).removeClass('error');

        $('span.error').remove();

        // Validate all inputs with the class "required"
        $('.required',$formId).each(function(){
            var inputVal = $("#doctorId").val();
            var $parentTag = $("#doctorId").parent();
            if(inputVal == ''){
                $parentTag.addClass('error').append($error.clone().text('Required Field'));
            }

        // Run the email validation using the regex for those input items also having class "email"


        // Check passwords match for inputs with class "password"


        });

        // All validation complete - Check if any errors exist
        // If has errors



        if ($('span.error').length > 0) {

            $('span.error').each(function(){

                // Set the distance for the error animation
                var distance = 5;

                // Get the error dimensions
                var width = $(this).outerWidth();

                // Calculate starting position
                var start = width + distance;

                // Set the initial CSS
                $(this).show().css({
                    display: 'block',
                    opacity: 0,
                    right: -start+'px'
                })
                // Animate the error message
                .animate({
                    right: -width+'px',
                    opacity: 1
                }, 'slow');

            });
        } else {
            this.form.action = "DoctorServlet?method=search";
            $formId.submit();
        }
        // Prevent form submission
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    // Fade out error message when input field gains focus
    $('.required').focus(function(){
        var $parent = $(this).parent();
        $parent.removeClass('error');
        $('span.error',$parent).fadeOut();
    });
});
```

---

```
public class DoctorServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String sDocId = request.getParameter("doctorId");
        Integer dId = Integer.parseInt(sDocId);
        String speciality = request.getParameter("speciality");
        String experience = request.getParameter("experience");
        String qualification = request.getParameter("qualification");
        String sempId = request.getParameter("employeeId");

        String action = request.getParameter("method");

        Doctors d = new Doctors();

        if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("add")) {
            Integer empId = Integer.parseInt(sempId);
            d.setDocId(dId);
            d.setEmpId(empId);
            d.setExp(experience);
            d.setSumOfQn(qualification);
            d.setSpeciality(speciality);
            try {
                boolean result = new Doctors().insertDoctor(d);
                if (result == true) {

                    request.setAttribute("add", "success");
                }
                request.getRequestDispatcher("doctor_result.jsp").forward(request, response);
                // response.sendRedirect("doctor_result.jsp");



            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(DoctorServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

        } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("delete")) {

            d.setDocId(dId);
            try {
                boolean result = d.removeDoctor(dId);
                if (result == true) {

                    request.setAttribute("delete", "success");
                }
                request.getRequestDispatcher("doctor_result.jsp").forward(request, response);
                response.sendRedirect("doctor_result.jsp");

            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(DoctorServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        else if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("update")){
            try {
                boolean result=d.updateDoctor(dId, experience, qualification);
                if(result==true){

                    request.setAttribute("update", "success");
                }
                request.getRequestDispatcher("doctor_result.jsp").forward(request, response);

            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(DoctorServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        else if(action.equalsIgnoreCase("search")){
            try {
                ResultSet rs=d.searchDoctor(dId);
                while(rs.next()){
                    int docId=rs.getInt(1);
                    request.setAttribute("docId", docId);
                    String exp=rs.getString(3);
                    request.setAttribute("exp",exp);
                    String spec=rs.getString(2);
                    request.setAttribute("speciality", spec);
                    String qlf=rs.getString(5);
                    request.setAttribute("qlf", qlf);

                }
                request.getRequestDispatcher("doctor_result").forward(request, response);

            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(DoctorServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: You need to rephrase your question. What do you meant - `..But when I put the same name in the action and servlet condition, I get url not found error`

Comment: Do you mean that if your method parameter is equal to one of your cases dealt with in your servlet (i.e. "add", "update" or "search") then you get a 404 but if you set method=[some-other-string] then you don't? Give examples of what works and what doesn't. BTW your "search" case forwards to doctor_result whereas the others forward to doctor_result.jsp - is this intentional?